# How to record the mouse cursor while recording the screen?

Tags: 22.04

When hitting `prt scr` key I get the interface to select screen recording where I can select what to record and hit start. However it does not record the courser. Is this possible to record as well? If so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the interface that pops up, at the bottom-right there is a pointer icon, if you click that before you record - it's the toggle option for recording the mouse pointer.

Comment: I see the icon, but in activating it, nothing changes; I still have no mouse cursor when recording video.