Integrated GNOME Shell screencast recording not showing mouse pointer
System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, GNOME 42.9 X11
Although the option is toggled on, the pointer is visible in screenshots but not on the video recordings.
What can that be?

Did you see this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478561/how-to-record-the-mouse-cursor-while-recording-the-screen

The Pointer works in both 22.04 and 24.04
Push PS, choose Picture, press the pointer and see that it shows, change to record screen and start recording, once done, you will see the pointer in the video.
In both 22.04 and 24.04 if you choose first the video you will not see if pointer is on or off, but if you press on it, it will turn on or off.

Here is a video with the pointer enabled on Ubuntu 24.04.  I'm moving it around the screen but it is not shown.  I then highlight text on the page.
https://youtu.be/GrDPWfizqys

On Gnome Shell version 46 running wayland and Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.lts the pointer shows. I just tested it.

And I checked with 22.04 now and it also shows, The standard gis ru on both computers, no deviation of shell or anything else.

I'm also running Gnome 46 and Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, still not working.  The only strange thing I'm doing is running three monitors and am using the NVidia driver 550.90.07.

Is it possible that your mouse is someplace else? Do a test, disconnect all screens and run PS see if mouse shows. Then you know where problem is.

Make sure in the Settings you have only one screen when testing.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407422/screenshot-selection-in-22-04 before yoput thry the other app try removing gnomescreenshot and installing it.
